# Question was at 4 votes, now is at 2

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

I don't understand why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031542/catch-all-signals-that-would-stop-a-program) has lost votes. [I haven't been downvoted today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6850771/md-xf?tab=reputation), and yesterday the vote count was still at 4. I was the victim/recipient of serial upvoting once, but I posted the question after the account had been removed and the voting corrected. Anyone have any ideas about why my question has gone from 4 votes to 2?

Note: I haven't lost any reputation from this change (as far as I can tell).

Comment: The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40031542/timeline) suggests you only did receive those 2 upvotes. Are you sure you are remembering correctly?

Comment: @RadLexus Positive. I remember anticipating that *one last upvote* so that the question would appear on my StackExchange 'top posts'.

Comment: does the timeline show un-upvotes? seems like it just shows total result, so if someone upvoted, then un-upvoted that same day, it wouldn't be reported in the timeline.

Comment: @KevinB I had the upvotes for over a week.

Comment: They were maybe invalidated?

Comment: then my best guess would be some votes were invalidated.

Comment: @KevinB On top of this, I've just recieved a downvote, along with 3 upvotes on other random questions. Am I again being serial voted?

Comment: @MDXF no, you posted a link to your question on meta. Likely a few of us clicking vote and watching timeline too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two users who upvoted that post were deleted about a month ago.

That *should've* caused the score to recalculate that evening, but... Perhaps a scheduled task failed to run. In any case, someone upvoted the post a couple of days ago, which would've prompted the previously-referenced scheduled task to kick in after a while and update the post's score. Presumably that's what you observed.

Also... Check your email.

Comment: Would you mind removing that last line as it doesn't technically contribute to the answer? Thanks.